# Problem running legacy program in Windows 7 using DDE

Tags: windows, windows-7, dde, progress-4gl, openedge

My admin folks have encountered a big problem, and I'm relaying their plight to SO:

We have a legacy database application (written in Progress 4GL/OpenEdge) that invokes **WordPerfect X3** in order to generate a report.  The path to the WordPerfect executable is hard-coded within the database app, as well as the location of scanned PDFs that are to be inserted into the database, *and we have no way to modify the program*.

Most of our workstations have been successfully migrated from **WinXP** to **Win7**, and the legacy application works fine UNTIL it tries to invoke WordPerfect, saying it can't find the executable (even with X3 installed in the exact same path used on WinXP) ... same with the scanned document folder.

Any suggestions?

---

**UPDATE:**

I spent this morning helping my admin folks with the various suggestions you all provided ... we checked file permissions, looked at the compiled (.r) files with a Hex Editor (thanks @Tom and @Ernest), and did a *search in files* inside all source code (.p) with Notepad++.

***Here's what I found:***  the program is NOT invoking WordPerfect directly (*as I was originally informed*), but instead is using DDE.  Here's the error message that Progress 4GL produces:

[image: DDE INITIATE Failed. (3153)]

I am aware that there are issues with DDE and Win7, so I was wondering if there's a work-around, maybe registry keys that need to be modified or something to that affect.

I'm including an excerpt from the source code below, hoping that somebody recognizes what's going on (I'm NOT familiar with Progress 4GL, so it's all greek to me):

```
/* setup DDE communicaiton with WordPerfect 12   */
/* and perform the merge of the various document */

DEFINE VARIABLE sys             AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE mline           AS CHAR FORMAT "x(220)" NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE intResult       AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE err-status AS INTEGER.

{GLOBVAR.I}
DEFINE VAR C-Win AS WIDGET-HANDLE NO-UNDO.

DEFINE FRAME FRAME-b
    WITH 1 DOWN KEEP-TAB-ORDER OVERLAY 
         SIDE-LABELS NO-UNDERLINE THREE-D 
         AT COL 13 ROW 4.1
         SIZE 11 BY 2
         TITLE "FRAMEWP".

IF SESSION:DISPLAY-TYPE = "GUI":U THEN
  CREATE WINDOW C-Win ASSIGN
         HIDDEN             = YES
         HEIGHT             = 4
         WIDTH              = 20
         MAX-HEIGHT         = 4
         MAX-WIDTH          = 20
         VIRTUAL-HEIGHT     = 4
         VIRTUAL-WIDTH      = 20
         RESIZE             = yes
         SCROLL-BARS        = no
         STATUS-AREA        = no
         BGCOLOR            = ?
         FGCOLOR            = ?
         KEEP-FRAME-Z-ORDER = yes
         THREE-D            = yes
         MESSAGE-AREA       = no
         SENSITIVE          = YES.

IF SESSION:DISPLAY-TYPE = "GUI":U AND VALID-HANDLE(C-Win)
THEN C-Win:HIDDEN = NO.
  VIEW FRAME DEFAULT-FRAME IN WINDOW C-Win.
  VIEW FRAME FRAME-b IN WINDOW C-Win.
  C-Win.

ENABLE ALL WITH FRAME FRAME-B TITLE "".
ASSIGN FRAME FRAME-B:VISIBLE = FALSE. 

OS-DELETE VALUE(pass-txtout).
PAUSE 1 NO-MESSAGE IN WINDOW c-win.
OS-DELETE VALUE(pass-mergedoc).

pass-shelldoc = '"' + trim(pass-shelldoc) + '"'.
pass-shelldoc = TRIM(pass-shelldoc).

pass-txtfile = '"' + TRIM(pass-txtfile) + '"'.
pass-txtfile = TRIM(pass-txtfile).

pass-txtout = '"' + TRIM(pass-txtout) + '"'.
pass-txtout = TRIM(pass-txtout).

pass-mergedoc = '"' + TRIM(pass-mergedoc) + '"'.
pass-mergedoc = TRIM(pass-mergedoc).

DDE INITIATE sys FRAME FRAME FRAME-B:HANDLE APPLICATION "wpwin13_macros" TOPIC "COMMANDS".

/* create a wp doc from the pass-txtfile just created */
mline = "Application (WordPerfect; " + '"WordPerfect"' + '; Default!; "EN")'.
mline = TRIM(mline).
DDE EXECUTE sys COMMAND mline.

mline = "FileNew ()".
mline = TRIM(mline).
DDE EXECUTE sys COMMAND mline.

mline = "ImportSetFileName (Filename: " + pass-txtfile + ")".
mline = TRIM(mline).
DDE EXECUTE sys COMMAND mline.

mline = "ImportSetSource (SourceType: ASCII!)".
mline = TRIM(mline).
DDE EXECUTE sys COMMAND mline.

mline = "ImportSetDestination (DestinationType: MergeData!)".
mline = TRIM(mline).
DDE EXECUTE sys COMMAND mline.

mline = "ImportSetSizeToFit (State: No!)".
mline = TRIM(mline).
DDE EXECUTE sys COMMAND mline.

mline = "ImportSetAsciiFieldDelimiter (FieldDelimiter: " + '"^"' + ")".
mline = TRIM(mline).
DDE EXECUTE sys COMMAND mline.

mline = "ImportSetAsciiRecordDelimiter (RecordDelimiter: " + '"%"' + ")".
mline = TRIM(mline).
DDE EXECUTE sys COMMAND mline.

mline = "ImportSetAsciiStrip (StripChars: " + '""' + ")".
mline = TRIM(mline).
DDE EXECUTE sys COMMAND mline.

mline = "ImportSetAsciiEncap (EncapsulationChar: " + '"""' + '""' + ")".
mline = TRIM(mline).
DDE EXECUTE sys COMMAND mline.

mline = "ImportDoImport ()".
mline = TRIM(mline).
DDE EXECUTE sys COMMAND mline.

mline = "WAIT(10)".
mline = TRIM(mline).
DDE EXECUTE sys COMMAND mline.

mline = "FileSave (Filename: " + pass-txtout + "; ExportType: WordPerfect_6_7_8!; yes!)".
mline = TRIM(mline).
DDE EXECUTE sys COMMAND mline.

mline = "Close()".
mline = TRIM(mline).
DDE EXECUTE sys COMMAND mline.

/* perform the merge using sheldoc, pass-txtout and pass-shelldoc */
mline = "Application (WordPerfect; " + '"WordPerfect"' + '; Default!; "EN")'.
mline = TRIM(mline).
DDE EXECUTE sys COMMAND mline.

mline = "MergeRUN(Formfile!;" + pass-shelldoc + ";DataFile!;".
mline = TRIM(mline).
DDE EXECUTE sys COMMAND mline.

mline = mline + pass-txtout + ";TOFILE!;" + pass-mergedoc + ")".
mline = TRIM(mline).
DDE EXECUTE sys COMMAND mline.

mline = "CLOSE()".
mline = TRIM(mline).
DDE EXECUTE sys COMMAND mline.

IF substring(pass-mergedoc,16,3) = "D12" THEN.
ELSE
    DO:
    mline = "FileOpen (Filename: " + pass-mergedoc + ")".
    mline = TRIM(mline).
    DDE EXECUTE sys COMMAND mline.

    mline = "AppMaximize ()".
    mline = TRIM(mline).
    DDE EXECUTE sys COMMAND mline.

    mline = "APPRESTORE ()".
    mline = TRIM(mline).
    DDE EXECUTE sys COMMAND mline.
    END.

DDE TERMINATE sys NO-ERROR.
 :
 :
```

Comment: Does it also fail if it's executed in admin mode ('Run as Administrator')? I'm wondering if it's a permission issue on the location where WP is installed.

Comment: Is it the 64-bit edition of Windows 7?  Is the path in system32 or Program Files?

Comment: What is the hardcoded path that it can not find?

Comment: @Luke: the program runs in Win7 (32-bit) ... haven't tried in 64-bit yet.  

@Eric: running as admin still produces the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that it sounds a lot like a permissions problem.

None the less...  are you sure that you have no way to modify it?  That isn't the sort of functionality that would typically be delivered by a vendor -- it sounds more like a custom modification.

Do you have .p or .w files hanging around?  (These are Progress 4GL source code.)  Or only .r files?  (This is the compiled code.)

Run "showcfg" (the "config" icon on the start menu) -- if you have development licenses it may be more a case of not knowing how to change it than not having the ability to change it.

Comment: We do have access to the source code (.p and .w files), but the software was provided by a third party and there are certain licensing issues that cam about when we "suggested" to modify their code.  Long story short: the third party wants a LOT of money to make the necessary changes.

Answer (score 1):

The program file which you have "no way to modify" could, in fact, be edited with a hex editor; did that plenty of times, back in the day. The paths are almost certain to be sitting inside the binary file in readable text format.

Barring that, you could run XP inside a VM image (i.e., VMware player) and install the program on that; it them may be happier.

Comment: I hadn't considered the Hex Editor path ... I also remember using that approach "back in the day" and didn't consider it.